What is the recommended collation for a PostgreSQL unique e-mail column?
Most places recommend for unique e-mail indexes using either a lower(email) index, or a datatype citext.
But the manual for citext suggests using a collation for all cases instead of citext now:

Consider using nondeterministic collations instead of this module.

So, currently, what is the recommended way to treat a unique e-mail column in PostgreSQL?
Index on lower()? citext still? Or if collation, which one exactly?


if collate, which one exactly?

Whichever one you prefer - it's not necessarily about picking a specific collation out of the built-in list, but configuring one that way. As demonstrated in the doc:
demo at db<>fiddle
CREATE COLLATION case_insensitive (
  provider = icu, 
  locale = 'und-u-ks-level2', --undefined(root,generic), but you can pick a language
  deterministic = false);
SELECT 'a' = 'A' COLLATE case_insensitive; -- true

If you're asking about which locale is recommended for the case-insensitive collation, I'd say that's the generic one above but ultimately it won't matter. Others mainly differ in how they sort things, and unless specifically configured for the purpose, I don't think they'll disagree on equality you want for unique.
I assumed you're asking which particular collation is the recommendation, in which case there's no such thing - a standard installation doesn't ship with a built-in case-insensitive collation out of the box. Japanese, Arabic and Chinese are examples of "case-insensitive" languages (characters don't have upper/lower variants) but collations based on them aren't themselves case-insensitive when they deal with other alphabets.
If you're asking about performance, in this test on 150k 90% unique random samples as well as another one I ran on 10M, the expression index using lower() on a text column with collate "C" tends to perform best, followed closely by a regular index on the text column using the case-insensitive icu collation. citext stays way behind.


My point is that the character set for email is not open to interpretation. email rfc uses ascii, with several chars removed, it doesn't care about internationalization standards.

There's more than one "email RFC" so you could argue that even the meaning of "email RFC" is open to interpretation. Also, it is not "ASCII-only, with several chars removed", or at least it hasn't been for a while now. Here's a relatively old thread discussing these topics, linking a nice example at Wikipedia:

The example addresses below would not be handled by RRFC 5322 based servers, but are permitted by RFC 6530. Servers compliant with this will be able to handle these:

Latin alphabet with diacritics: Pelé@example.com
Greek alphabet: δοκιμή@παράδειγμα.δοκιμή
Traditional Chinese characters: 我買@屋企.香港
Japanese characters: 二ノ宮@黒川.日本
Cyrillic characters: медведь@с-балалайкой.рф
Devanagari characters: संपर्क@डाटामेल.भारत


I feel like I need to draw a line: character sets are about encoding. Collations you asked about are for sorting and equality, and most work with all encoding options. You can tell by checking pg_collation.collencoding = -1:

collencoding int4
Encoding in which the collation is applicable, or -1 if it works for any encoding

In case you wanted to ask about email address validation and normalisation through a column constraint, that's a slightly different question.

the one that is a perfect fit for email is not exactly a personal preference :)

Thanks for updating the answer. My point is that the character set for email is not open to interpretation. email rfc uses ascii, with several chars removed, it doesn't care about internationalization standards.

thanks again for the edits! That linked question is pretty excellent but goes a little beyond of what i needed, learned a lot though ...my application already does encoding of utf to puny code on the domain, and localpart/dot-atom, you bring a good point about utf8, but realistically, support for RFC 6531/SMTPUTF8 is very low and spotty. Still undecided if i want to support this.

"character sets are about encoding. Collations you asked about are for sorting and equality" Very good point. that is the root of my question though. Their own manual on the citext character type have a big red box telling to instead consider "nondeterministic collations".
